# Is there a Delphi IDE plugin for XML file editing, validation, formatting?

Tags: xml, delphi, ide, plugins

Are there (free or commercial) IDE editor plugins for Delphi which

- show valid XML tags and parameters automatically while editing (like CodeInsight for HTML does it already) or suggest the correct closing tags, matching the current open tag?
- validate a XML file in the IDE editor against its XSD, or to check its well-formedness?
- format a XML file which is open in the IDE editor (this would be useful for configuration files and scripts)?

These editing capabilities could also be useful for XHTML web page documents in IntraWeb / WebSnap applications, WSDL (Web Service description) and XSD (XML Schema) files, making web application and web service development easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such addin. All programs suggested above are good. I personally use XML Spy.

Answer (score 2):

As far as an external tool could satisfy your needs, there is the **free** [XmlNotepad](http://www.codeplex.com/xmlnotepad) which can do all this.
I use it as (very) good alternative to XmlSpy.

Answer (score 1):

Although your requirements are valid, they are too specialized to be included in a [Delphi](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi) IDE plugin, I think you best option is to use an IDE especially made to handle XML files as [Stylus Studio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/) or **[Altova XML Editor](http://www.altova.com/)**.

[image]
<sub>(source: [altova.com](https://www.altova.com/images/shots/XMLSpy_xml_editor.gif))</sub>

Comment: Validation of an XML file which is open in the editor is no rocket science using the already built-in support for MSXML which can do schema validation, and formatting too. It looks like a business opportunity if I think of the price for XMLSpy ($200 and up) ;)